# How to expose the Redis+Sentinel to outside in aks cluster

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, redis, azure-aks

I am using [Given Link](https://github.com/marcel-dempers/docker-development-youtube-series/tree/master/storage/redis/kubernetes) to create 3 node Redis cluster(1 master and 2 slaves) and 3 node sentinel.

I have exposed sentinel though nginx ingress still not able to connect.

Error: Redis Client On Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-0.redis.stress-tr.svc.cluster.local Config right?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sentinel
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  rules:
    - host: sentinel.example.com
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: sentinel
                port:
                  number: 5000
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - sentinel.example.com
      secretName: tls-sentinel
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to expose service over HTTPS.

1. You must create  a Kubernetes secret to host the certificate and private key

```bash
kubectl create secret tls your-secret --key path-to-key --cert path-to-cert
```

Read [Let's Encrypt for Kubernetes](https://github.com/nabsul/k8s-letsencrypt)

2. ingres.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: yourapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway

spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: your-secret
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: yourservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

3. Apply

```bash
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
```

You can install redis-sentinel with Helm on your cluster

```
helm install redis -n redis — set sentinel.enabled=true,sentinel.quorum=3,cluster.slaveCount=3 bitnami/redis
```

Comment: I am getting this error 
Error: Redis Client On Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-0.redis.stress-tr.svc.cluster.local Config right?

Comment: what does kubectl get pods show?

Comment: I want to expose sentinel with ingress controller and check with code . also all pods are running fine.